# How to put color on a selected menu inside a menu sub list in slidenav

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-controller="ListBottomSheetCtrl" class="md-padding bottomSheetdemoBasicUsage" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
    <div class="cnt">
        <div class="menu-item" ng-click="toggle(1); open1=!open1">
            <md-list layout="row" layout-padding="" class="layout-row" layout-align="start center" flex> 
                <span class="title flex" flex=""> Menu Item</span>
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" ng-class="{'rotate180': open1, 'rotate-back': !open1}"></i>
            </md-list>
            <div class="sub-menu" ng-animate="'animate'" >
                <md-menu-item ng-if="menuIsOpen===1" ng-repeat="item in data"  >
                    <md-button>
                        <div layout="row" flex="">
                            <a ui-sref="{{item.link}}">
                                <p flex=""><i class="fa fa-{{item.icon}}"></i> {{item.title}}</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </md-button>
                </md-menu-item>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-item" ng-click="toggle(2); open2=!open2">
            <md-list layout="row" layout-padding="" class="layout-row" layout-align="start center" flex> 
                <span class="title flex" flex=""> Menu Item 2</span>
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" ng-class="{'rotate180': open2, 'rotate-back': !open2}"></i>
            </md-list>
            <div class="sub-menu" ng-animate="'animate'" >
                <md-menu-item ng-if="menuIsOpen===2" ng-repeat="item in data2">
                    <md-button>
                        <div layout="row" flex="">
                            <a ui-sref="{{item.link}}">
                                <p flex=""><i class="fa fa-{{item.icon}}"></i> {{item.title}}</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </md-button>
                </md-menu-item>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

Comment: Please add more information, don't just put all html code you have and say put color. No one understands that, put some detailed explanation what you want to do and how did you try to do it yourself and failed. If you haven't tried anything go out google a bit try it yourself first, if you fail then try again here.

Comment: Im nt able to add more code into this.. i cn understand u..

Comment: https://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/pRNLwo?editors=1010 -- this is the link which i surfed it out frm google

Comment: but how do you want to put color, dynamically in angular, depending on some parameters or just simple css? Do you want to put background color on items or normal text color? you didn't say anything just wrote "I want color in submenu" question, I didn't need more code I needed more explanation what exactly you want to do because you have no explanation except title.

Comment: While selecting one of those sub menu ...a color has to appear that i hve selected tht menu

Comment: That sentence was exactly what I needed to help you, check my answer below, next time when you ask question please post everything you think of in your question. You'll get answer lot quicker if people understand what you need right away.

Answer (score 0):

Well after some checking I noticed that logic has it's bit buggy so I reworked it a bit, main thing is now you don't have properties on $scope open1, open2, open3 and open4, you now have only one array and everything's done with that array. You will notice that you need to pass 0 instead of 1 for first open element because it's looking at array value.

**html:**

```
<div ng-controller="ListBottomSheetCtrl" class="md-padding bottomSheetdemoBasicUsage" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
    <div class="cnt">
        <div class="menu-item" ng-click="toggle(1);">
            <md-list layout="row" layout-padding="" ng-class="{'orange': listOfItems[0]}" class="layout-row" layout-align="start center" flex> 
                <span class="title flex" flex=""> Menu Item</span>
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" ng-class="{'rotate180': listOfItems[0], 'rotate-back': !listOfItems[0]}"></i>
            </md-list>
            <div class="sub-menu" ng-animate="'animate'" >
                <md-menu-item ng-if="menuIsOpen===1" ng-repeat="item in data"  >
                    <md-button>
                        <div layout="row" flex="">
                            <a ui-sref="{{item.link}}">
                                <p flex=""><i class="fa fa-{{item.icon}}"></i> {{item.title}}</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </md-button>
                </md-menu-item>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-item" ng-click="toggle(2);">
            <md-list layout="row" layout-padding="" ng-class="{'orange': listOfItems[1]}"  class="layout-row" layout-align="start center" flex> 
                <span class="title flex" flex=""> Menu Item 2</span>
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" ng-class="{'rotate180': listOfItems[1], 'rotate-back': !listOfItems[1]}"></i>
            </md-list>
            <div class="sub-menu" ng-animate="'animate'" >
                <md-menu-item ng-if="menuIsOpen===2" ng-repeat="item in data2">
                    <md-button>
                        <div layout="row" flex="">
                            <a ui-sref="{{item.link}}">
                                <p flex=""><i class="fa fa-{{item.icon}}"></i> {{item.title}}</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </md-button>
                </md-menu-item>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

**javascript:**

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngAnimate'])

    .controller('ListBottomSheetCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = 
        [{
            title: 'Home',
            icon: 'home',
            link: '/page1/'
        }, {
            title: 'Email Us',
            icon: 'envelope',
            link: '/page2/'
        }, {
            title: 'Profile',
            icon: 'user',
            link: '/page3/'
        }, {
            title: 'Print',
            icon: 'print',
            link: '/page4/'
        }];

    $scope.data2 = 
        [{
            title: 'Home 2',
            icon: 'home',
            link: '/page1/'
        }, {
            title: 'Email Us 2',
            icon: 'envelope',
            link: '/page2/'
        }, {
            title: 'Profile 2',
            icon: 'user',
            link: '/page3/'
        }, {
            title: 'Print 2',
            icon: 'print',
            link: '/page4/'
        }];

    $scope.listOfItems = [false,false,false,false];
    $scope.toggle = function(itemPos) {
        if($scope.listOfItems[itemPos-1]) {
            $scope.listOfItems = [false,false,false,false];
            itemPos = 0;
        }else {
            $scope.listOfItems = [false,false,false,false];
            $scope.listOfItems[itemPos-1] = true;
        }
        $scope.menuIsOpen = itemPos;        
    }
})
```

In css I just added class:

```
.orange { 
  background: orange 
};
```

Everything is here:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rGWJKo?editors=1010

Comment: see in menu 1 there is a sub menu in that if i select on those color must appear & if i click on email us option it wll go to tht page.. also I need to  show tht selection in that menu.

Comment: do you have ui-router on your site? if you do, you will need to put states for each site, that way we can know which page is opened, there's another way to read it out of $window but using ui-router is best way and standard.

Comment: No ui-router jst a link to a page

Comment: I think you do have ui-router since you are using ui-sref for links which is ui-router thingy can you check about that, then you could inject $state and get current state of the app (opened link) from there

Comment: instead of ui-sref im using ui-href link

Comment: there's no ui-href that I know of, ui-sref is angular ui router. I can't help you anymore if you're not using ui-router. There maybe is a workaround approach that you can't check on codepen, and here's example. I commented code what you need to do: https://codepen.io/pegla/pen/rGWJKo#/gfa

Comment: leave it..u jst help me..in setting color only to the sub menu..not that MENU1..MENU2 and also if i select home...color for home shld appear..and it should remain there untill next selection is made

Comment: well my second pen is working like that however you will need some smaller code modifications to make it work, since you can't test this on codepen you will need to do it locally. $window variable has hash property which you will need to check against item.link Check comments and you will be able to work it out.